# Matplotlib: non-GUI backend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been struggling to fix the following error which occurred upon uninstalling and reinstalling Anaconda.

> C:\Users\Riccardo\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py:445: UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
>     % get_backend())

Surprisingly, out of all bar plots, only one of them which is a frequency plot is affected. Prior to reinstalling, it would give a spectrum of colors by itself, whereas the current plot shows a single color for all of the bars:

```
pd.value_counts(DataFrame['Country']).plot('barh', ax=Subplots)
```

For the remaining bar plots the colors are passed in explicitly:

```
Subplot1.bar(Lables, Values_Rows, align="center", width= 0.5, color= ['m','c','gold','yellowgreen']
```

Here, the color of the bars remained unaffected upon reinstalling Anaconda.

Could anybody shed some light into this? Thanking you in advance!

Comment: The color issue is simply that you have a newer version of pandas, which does not show colors by default (I suspect that in general people do not want to get a rainbow out when plotting bars). Concerning the user warning, this should not occur and may be a bug. But the information provided is not sufficient to find out.

Comment: Many thanks for replying to my query. To get a rainbow our of pd.value_counts(DataFrame['Country']).plot(), would I have to invoke colormaps?

Comment: Well, you need a list of colors. You can use colormaps to generate such list, e.g. `color=plt.cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0,1,len(s)))` where `s` is the `Series` you plot.